# Providing a list of data to non-users securely

Tags: security, data, data-export, user-management, guest-user

We have a requirement to send data to a list of people who are not users.

This data is, and should be treated as, highly secure.

These people are owed this data and are allowed to view it but it should not be sent to them in an email because email is insecure and 'HIPPA'.

So: the people are identified as Contacts in Salesforce. The data is a list of Leads.

These 'Leads' are able to be identified as having an existing relationship with at least one of the Contacts.

The Contacts want to see the list of Leads that they are able, and have permission, to view in a single place.

I cannot automatically create and store the lists of Leads in n csv files (where n is the total number of Contacts)

We have Marketing Cloud - perhaps I can create and send a unique link that each creates a list for the specific Contact?

To be clear this isn't another "Why aren't reports able to be scheduled as csv files" etc (though they should be) - I need a way, using Salesforce and/or Marketing Cloud to create and Display/Export/Send a list of Lead data that people (identified as Contacts, not Users) can access.

Comment: How do you do it now if it's manual? You said no to email, but what if you set up email relay? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_email_relay_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: I think this is a new process. If not then this is certainly a new method. Also - they will not relay emails from external (Salesforce or Marketing Cloud)

Comment: You could potentially standup a site where the external users will have to provide contact info (to identify the external user/contact - maybe email address, ....) and have a decryption process in the back-end. Provided that you have a way to store the encrypted data (not sure if there is any automation requirements for the Lead management piece) maybe in a custom object. Then the only secure exchange between you and the external users is providing the keys to decrypt the payload. Just an idea...